# What is the actual drawback of "CheckHostIP no"?

Tags: ssh, ssh-host-key

What are the actual security implications of setting `CheckHostIP no` in SSH client configuration?

There are some discussions about this (eg. https://askubuntu.com/a/48339) and recommendations to set it to `yes` for extra security (eg. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8479, https://serverfault.com/a/193634), but some people also say it doesn't really matter for security (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/285551).

What kinds of attacks are possible with `CheckHostIP no` that are prevented/detected with `CheckHostIP yes`?

Afterthought: does `CheckHostIP no` mean that the SSH key of the target host is not checked *at all*? If so, how do I securely connect to a machine with dynamic IP address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CheckHostIP no` means that ssh does not check the host IP address in the known_hosts file. So only if `CheckHostIP` is set to `no` a DNS server can return a different IP address as written in the known_hosts file without a warning of the ssh client.

For example an entry in a (unhashed) known_hosts file could be:

```
www.example.org,1.2.3.4 ssh-rsa AAAA...njvPw==
```

If `CheckHostIP` is set to `no` a DNS server can return an different IP as 1.2.3.4 as address for www.example.org. But the SSH key is still checked. `CheckHostIP no` means only to expect that the IP is variable and to let key-checking against the hostname.

Therefore if (1) `CheckHostIP` is set to `no` and (2) an attacker can control the DNS and (3) has your private key he can setup a server which will first appear like the original one. That can be bad for confidentiality. Think about a backup server. But already if the preconditions 2+3 are met a attacker is able to compromise your system. With  `CheckHostIP no` only more further attacks are possible.

Comment: Don't you mean, "if an attacker has the private key for the host"?

Comment: **But the SSH key is still checked.**  That sentence should be in bold.

Comment: @jhfrontz well, it might depend on the value of `StrictHostKeyChecking` setting.